# Shortcut to save a note on Kindle for PC/MAC?

Tags: kindle, annotations

Whenever I want to save a note after I've finished typing on Kindle for PC/MAC I have to click on the "save" button by hand, which is very inconvenient. Is there a shortcut specifically designed for it, or is there any workaround?